# Left join using data.table

Tags: r, join, merge, data.table

Suppose I have two *data.table*'s:

dataA:

```
   A  B
1: 1 12
2: 2 13
3: 3 14
4: 4 15
```

dataB:

```
   A  B
1: 2 13
2: 3 14
```

and I have the following code:

```
merge_test = merge(dataA, dataB, by="A", all.data=TRUE)
```

I get:

```
   A B.x B.y
1: 2  13  13
2: 3  14  14
```

However, I want all the rows in dataA in the final merged table. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: A search should result in a number of questions that cover this. Here is one:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12773822/why-does-xy-join-of-data-tables-not-allow-a-full-outer-join-or-a-left-join

Comment: If you want to do a left join, you can use `all.x = TRUE`. If you want to do a full outer join, you can use `all = TRUE`.

Comment: Judging from votes, maybe consider changing accepted answer?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can try this:

```
# used data
# set the key in 'B' to the column which you use to join
A <- data.table(a = 1:4, b = 12:15)
B <- data.table(a = 2:3, b = 13:14, key = 'a') 

B[A]
```

Comment: This answer works fine if one data table key is subset of the other. Is there possibility to join if they intersect partially? For example if `A, B` are like:
`A <- data.table(a = 1:4, b = 12:15)
B <- data.table(a = 2:5, c = 13:16) `

Answer (score 184):

If you want to add the `b` values of `B` to `A`, then it's  best to join `A` with `B` and update `A` by reference as follows:

```
A[B, on = 'a', bb := i.b]
```

which gives:

> ```
> > A
>    a  b bb
> 1: 1 12 NA
> 2: 2 13 13
> 3: 3 14 14
> 4: 4 15 NA
> ```

This is a better approach than using `B[A, on='a']` because the latter just prints the result to the console. When you want to get the results back into `A`, you need to use `A <- B[A, on='a']` which will give you the same result.

The reason why `A[B, on = 'a', bb := i.b]` is better than `A <- B[A, on = 'a']` is memory efficiency. With `A[B, on = 'a', bb := i.b]` the location of `A` in memory stays the same:

> ```
> > address(A)
> [1] "0x102afa5d0"
> > A[B, on = 'a', bb := i.b]
> > address(A)
> [1] "0x102afa5d0"
> ```

While on the other hand with `A <- B[A, on = 'a']`, a new object is created and saved in memory as `A` and hence has another location in memory:

> ```
> > address(A)
> [1] "0x102abae50"
> > A <- B[A, on = 'a']
> > address(A)
> [1] "0x102aa7e30"
> ```

Using `merge` (`merge.data.table`) results in a similar change in memory location:

> ```
> > address(A)
> [1] "0x111897e00"
> > A <- merge(A, B, by = 'a', all.x = TRUE)
> > address(A)
> [1] "0x1118ab000"
> ```

For memory efficiency it is thus better to use an *'update-by-reference-join'* syntax:

```
A[B, on = 'a', bb := i.b]
```

Although this doesn't make a noticeable difference with small datasets like these, it does make a difference on large datasets for which `data.table` was designed.

Probably also worth mentioning is that the order of `A` stays the same.

---

To see the effect on speed and memory use, let's benchmark with some larger datasets (for data, see the 2nd part of the *used data*-section below):

```
library(bench)
bm <- mark(AA <- BB[AA, on = .(aa)],
           AA[BB, on = .(aa), cc := cc],
           iterations = 1)
```

which gives (only relevant measurements shown):

> ```
> > bm[,c(1,3,5)]
> # A tibble: 2 x 3
>   expression                         median mem_alloc
>   <bch:expr>                       <bch:tm> <bch:byt>
> 1 AA <- BB[AA, on = .(aa)]            4.98s     4.1GB
> 2 AA[BB, on = .(aa), `:=`(cc, cc)] 560.88ms   384.6MB
> ```

So, in this setup the *'update-by-reference-join'* is about 9 times faster and consumes 11 times less memory.

<sub>***NOTE: Gains in speed and memory use might differ in different setups.***</sub>

---

**Used data:**

```
# initial datasets
A <- data.table(a = 1:4, b = 12:15)
B <- data.table(a = 2:3, b = 13:14)

# large datasets for the benchmark
set.seed(2019)
AA <- data.table(aa = 1:1e8, bb = sample(12:19, 1e7, TRUE))
BB <- data.table(aa = sample(AA$a, 2e5), cc = sample(2:8, 2e5, TRUE))
```

Comment: Great answer.  Just to confirm, I assume the "i" in "A[B, bb:=i.b, on='a']" refers to the"i" in the general data.table "DT[i, j, by]" syntax?

Comment: @cbailiss Yes, `i.b` mean that in updating `A` with the join it should look t the `b`-column of `B`. In a similar way, with the `x.` prefix you can refer to columns of `A`.

Comment: @Jaap How would you manage the join by reference when there are multiple new columns created? Here the new column `bb := i.b` is created, which as you stated looks up the corresponding `b` column value in the `B` `data.table` corresponding to `i`. But what happens when you have many new columns that would potentially be created from merging (by reference) larger `data.tables`?

Comment: @Prevost [see here for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37994369/2204410), I hope that answers your question

Comment: @Jaap It does answer it, thank you. I was hoping for a less typing intensive way, but I guess the trade off is typing for a by reference update. If I have been piping `data.table` operations to create columns I typically pipe in a `merge()` where available, which avoids assigning a new `data.table`. But with smaller `data.tables` or where a new `data.table` must be created from a join I may use your answer above or stick with `merge()`. Thanks for the quick comment!

Comment: @Prevost the tric is in using `mget`, see also the last part of my answer under the link from my previous comment

Comment: I've never seen this `i.` and `x.` syntax from `data.table` documentation before. Great answer

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of completeness, I add the [`table.express`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/table.express/vignettes/table.express.html) version of an answer to your questions. `table.express` nicely extends the tidyverse language to `data.table` making it a handy tool to work fastly with huge datasets. Here is the solution using your datasets from the question above:

> `merge_test = dataA %>% left_join(dataB, by="A")`

A `left_join` keeps all rows from dataA in the joined dataset.

***Note***: You must load the packages `data.table` *and* `table.express`.

Comment: this is great! thanks - I had not heard of this package.

Comment: Can you explan how this works? Within tidyverse I could do `left_join(table1, table2, by = c("colname" = "colname")`. This doesn't work with table.express. I need an `on =` argument. However, I can't find any in the documentation.

Comment: @gernophil please have a look at the [join documentation](https://asardaes.github.io/table.express/articles/joins.html) for `table.express`. The second argument in `left_join`, which is `by="A"` above, is the `on =` argument you refer to. Optionally, you can use the variable name without quotes.