# Replace specific values based on another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, lookup

First, let's start with DataFrame 1 (DF1) :

```
DF1 <- data.frame(c("06/19/2016", "06/20/2016", "06/21/2016", "06/22/2016", 
                    "06/23/2016", "06/19/2016", "06/20/2016", "06/21/2016",
                    "06/22/2016", "06/23/2016"),
                  c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
                  c(149, 150, 151, 152, 155, 84, 83, 80, 81, 97),
                  c(101, 102, 104, 107, 99, 55, 55, 56, 57, 58),
                  c("MTL", "MTL", "MTL", "MTL", "MTL", "NY", "NY", 
                    "NY", "NY", "NY"))
colnames(DF1) <- c("date", "id", "sales", "cost", "city")
```

I also have DataFrame 2 (DF2) :

```
DF2 <- data.frame(c("06/19/2016", "06/27/2016", "06/22/2016", "06/23/2016"),
                  c(1, 1, 2, 2),
                  c(9999, 8888, 777, 555),
                  c("LON", "LON", "QC", "QC"))
colnames(DF2) <- c("date", "id", "sales", "city")
```

For every rows in DF1, I have to look if there is a row in DF2 that has the same date and id. If yes, I have to replace the values in DF1 by the values in DF2.

DF2 will always have less columns than DF1. If a column is not in DF2, I must keep the original value that was in DF1 for that specific column.

The final output would like this:

```
results <- data.frame(c("06/19/2016", "06/20/2016", "06/21/2016", "06/22/2016",
                        "06/23/2016", "06/19/2016", "06/20/2016", "06/21/2016",
                        "06/22/2016", "06/23/2016"),
                      c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
                      c(9999, 150, 151, 152, 155, 84, 83, 80, 777, 555),
                      c(101, 102, 104, 107, 99, 55, 55, 56, 57, 58),
                      c("LON", "MTL", "MTL", "MTL", "MTL", "NY", "NY", 
                        "NY", "QC", "QC"))
colnames(results) <- c("date", "id", "sales", "cost", "city")
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You could use the join functionality of the [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table)-package for this:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF1)
setDT(DF2)

DF1[DF2, on = .(date, id), `:=` (city = i.city, sales = i.sales)]
```

which gives:

> ```
> > DF1
>           date id sales cost city
>  1: 06/19/2016  1  9999  101  LON
>  2: 06/20/2016  1   150  102  MTL
>  3: 06/21/2016  1   151  104  MTL
>  4: 06/22/2016  1   152  107  MTL
>  5: 06/23/2016  1   155   99  MTL
>  6: 06/19/2016  2    84   55   NY
>  7: 06/20/2016  2    83   55   NY
>  8: 06/21/2016  2    80   56   NY
>  9: 06/22/2016  2   777   57   QC
> 10: 06/23/2016  2   555   58   QC
> ```

---

When you have many columns in both datasets, it is easier to use `mget` instead off typing all the column names. For the used data in the question it would look like:

```
DF1[DF2, on = .(date, id), names(DF2)[3:4] := mget(paste0("i.", names(DF2)[3:4]))]
```

When you want to construct a vector of columnnames that need to be added beforehand, you could do this as follows:

```
cols <- names(DF2)[3:4]
DF1[DF2, on = .(date, id), (cols) := mget(paste0("i.", cols))]
```

Comment: In the real dataset, DF1 has 416 columns and DF2 has 321 columns

Comment: If I try the mget strategy, but doing it in two steps, why do I get an error? `cols <-names(DF2)[3:4]` and `DF1[DF2, on = .(date, id),cols := mget(paste0("i.", cols))]` Thanks

Comment: @t.r you need to put `cols` between `()`; see the update of my answer

Answer (score 2):

```
df <- merge(DF1, DF2, by = c("date", "id"), all.x=TRUE)

tmp1 <- df[is.na(df$sales.y) & is.na(df$city.y),]
tmp1$sales.y <- NULL
tmp1$city.y <- NULL
names(tmp1)[names(tmp1) == "sales.x"] <- "sales"
names(tmp1)[names(tmp1) == "city.x"] <- "city"

tmp2 <- df[!is.na(df$sales.y) & !is.na(df$city.y),]
tmp2$sales.x <- NULL
tmp2$city.x <- NULL
names(tmp2)[names(tmp2) == "sales.y"] <- "sales"
names(tmp2)[names(tmp2) == "city.y"] <- "city"

results <- rbindlist(list(tmp1,tmp2), use.names= TRUE, fill = TRUE)
```

[image: See the result]

Answer (score 1):

```
df <- merge(DF1, DF2, by = c("date", "id"))
df$newcolumn <- ifelse(is.na(df$column.y), df$column.x, df$column.y, all.x = TRUE)
```

Replace `column` with your variable.

Comment: By using merge, I would only keep a limited number of rows. I have to keep the specific format of DF1. I can only replace values in DF1

Comment: Use `all.x = TRUE` to keep all rows of DF1

Comment: `all.x` is a parameter for `merge`, not for `ifelse` ;-)