# Simultaneous fuzzy and non-fuzzy join

Tags: r, join, fuzzyjoin

Say I have this data frame:

```
# Set random seed
set.seed(33550336)

# Number of IDs
n <- 5

# Create data frames
df <- data.frame(ID = rep(1:n, each = 10), 
                 loc = seq(10, 100, by =10))
#    ID loc
# 1   1  10
# 2   1  20
# 3   1  30
# 4   1  40
# 5   1  50
# 6   1  60
# 7   1  70
# 8   1  80
# 9   1  90
# 10  1 100
# 11  2  10
# 12  2  20
# 13  2  30
# 14  2  40
# 15  2  50
# 16  2  60
# 17  2  70
# 18  2  80
# 19  2  90
# 20  2 100
# 21  3  10
# 22  3  20
# 23  3  30
# 24  3  40
# 25  3  50
# 26  3  60
# 27  3  70
# 28  3  80
# 29  3  90
# 30  3 100
# 31  4  10
# 32  4  20
# 33  4  30
# 34  4  40
# 35  4  50
# 36  4  60
# 37  4  70
# 38  4  80
# 39  4  90
# 40  4 100
# 41  5  10
# 42  5  20
# 43  5  30
# 44  5  40
# 45  5  50
# 46  5  60
# 47  5  70
# 48  5  80
# 49  5  90
# 50  5 100
```

Now, I have a second data frame that I'd like to join to it:

```
df_alt <- data.frame(ID = rep(1:n, each = 10), 
                     loc = sample(1:100, 5 * n, replace = TRUE), 
                     value = runif(n))
#    ID loc     value
# 1   1  87 0.3202490
# 2   1  36 0.4724253
# 3   1  53 0.4750352
# 4   1   7 0.8744985
# 5   1  38 0.2016645
# 6   1  92 0.3202490
# 7   1  74 0.4724253
# 8   1  72 0.4750352
# 9   1  73 0.8744985
# 10  1  95 0.2016645
# 11  2  61 0.3202490
# 12  2   5 0.4724253
# 13  2  87 0.4750352
# 14  2  11 0.8744985
# 15  2  10 0.2016645
# 16  2  25 0.3202490
# 17  2  60 0.4724253
# 18  2  62 0.4750352
# 19  2  52 0.8744985
# 20  2  31 0.2016645
# 21  3   3 0.3202490
# 22  3  43 0.4724253
# 23  3  45 0.4750352
# 24  3  91 0.8744985
# 25  3  51 0.2016645
# 26  3  87 0.3202490
# 27  3  36 0.4724253
# 28  3  53 0.4750352
# 29  3   7 0.8744985
# 30  3  38 0.2016645
# 31  4  92 0.3202490
# 32  4  74 0.4724253
# 33  4  72 0.4750352
# 34  4  73 0.8744985
# 35  4  95 0.2016645
# 36  4  61 0.3202490
# 37  4   5 0.4724253
# 38  4  87 0.4750352
# 39  4  11 0.8744985
# 40  4  10 0.2016645
# 41  5  25 0.3202490
# 42  5  60 0.4724253
# 43  5  62 0.4750352
# 44  5  52 0.8744985
# 45  5  31 0.2016645
# 46  5   3 0.3202490
# 47  5  43 0.4724253
# 48  5  45 0.4750352
# 49  5  91 0.8744985
# 50  5  51 0.2016645
```

I'd like a perfect match for `ID` and the closest match for `loc`. I looked at the `fuzzyjoin` package, but unfortunately you cannot have different levels of fuzziness for different columns. That is, I cannot specify a perfect match for `ID` and a fuzzy match for `loc`. So, as a work around I do a left join by `ID`, calculate the distance between `loc.x` and `loc.y` (i.e., `loc`s from the `df` and `df_alt` data frames, respectively), group by `ID` and `loc.x`, sort by distance between `loc`s, and take the first row (i.e., the shortest distance):

```
# Bind and find nearest
df_res <- df %>% 
  left_join(df_alt, by = "ID") %>% 
  mutate(delta = abs(loc.x - loc.y)) %>% 
  group_by(ID, loc.x) %>% 
  arrange(delta) %>% 
  filter(row_number() == 1) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  arrange(ID, loc.x)

# # A tibble: 50 x 5
#       ID loc.x loc.y value delta
#     <int> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1      1    10     7 0.874     3
# 2      1    20     7 0.874    13
# 3      1    30    36 0.472     6
# 4      1    40    38 0.202     2
# 5      1    50    53 0.475     3
# 6      1    60    53 0.475     7
# 7      1    70    72 0.475     2
# 8      1    80    74 0.472     6
# 9      1    90    92 0.320     2
# 10     1   100    95 0.202     5
# 11     2    10    10 0.202     0
# 12     2    20    25 0.320     5
# 13     2    30    31 0.202     1
# 14     2    40    31 0.202     9
# 15     2    50    52 0.874     2
# 16     2    60    60 0.472     0
# 17     2    70    62 0.475     8
# 18     2    80    87 0.475     7
# 19     2    90    87 0.475     3
# 20     2   100    87 0.475    13
# 21     3    10     7 0.874     3
# 22     3    20     7 0.874    13
# 23     3    30    36 0.472     6
# 24     3    40    38 0.202     2
# 25     3    50    51 0.202     1
# 26     3    60    53 0.475     7
# 27     3    70    87 0.320    17
# 28     3    80    87 0.320     7
# 29     3    90    91 0.874     1
# 30     3   100    91 0.874     9
# 31     4    10    10 0.202     0
# 32     4    20    11 0.874     9
# 33     4    30    11 0.874    19
# 34     4    40    61 0.320    21
# 35     4    50    61 0.320    11
# 36     4    60    61 0.320     1
# 37     4    70    72 0.475     2
# 38     4    80    74 0.472     6
# 39     4    90    92 0.320     2
# 40     4   100    95 0.202     5
# 41     5    10     3 0.320     7
# 42     5    20    25 0.320     5
# 43     5    30    31 0.202     1
# 44     5    40    43 0.472     3
# 45     5    50    51 0.202     1
# 46     5    60    60 0.472     0
# 47     5    70    62 0.475     8
# 48     5    80    91 0.874    11
# 49     5    90    91 0.874     1
# 50     5   100    91 0.874     9
```

This isn't particularly efficient, but gives the desired result. The problem arises when the data frame gets large. Rerunning the above code with a sufficiently large `n` produces the following error:

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size...

I think this is because the left join is producing an unnecessarily  huge data frame. Clearly, join-then-filter isn't the best strategy. But what *is* the best way to do a fuzzy and non-fuzzy join simultaneously?

Comment: In fuzzyjoin, you actually can specify different levels of fuzziness using multiple match_fun 's but it can get complicated. But it looks like data.table has good capabilities for this task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion the [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) package is best suited for this job:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
setDT(df_alt)

df_alt[df
       , on = .(ID, loc)
       , roll = "nearest"
       , .(ID, loc.x = i.loc, loc.y = x.loc, value, delta = abs(i.loc - x.loc))]
```

which gives:

> ```
>     ID loc.x loc.y     value delta
>  1:  1    10     7 0.8744985     3
>  2:  1    20     7 0.8744985    13
>  3:  1    30    36 0.4724253     6
>  4:  1    40    38 0.2016645     2
>  5:  1    50    53 0.4750352     3
>  6:  1    60    53 0.4750352     7
>  7:  1    70    72 0.4750352     2
>  8:  1    80    74 0.4724253     6
>  9:  1    90    92 0.3202490     2
> 10:  1   100    95 0.2016645     5
> 11:  2    10    10 0.2016645     0
> 12:  2    20    25 0.3202490     5
> 13:  2    30    31 0.2016645     1
> 14:  2    40    31 0.2016645     9
> 15:  2    50    52 0.8744985     2
> 16:  2    60    60 0.4724253     0
> 17:  2    70    62 0.4750352     8
> 18:  2    80    87 0.4750352     7
> 19:  2    90    87 0.4750352     3
> 20:  2   100    87 0.4750352    13
> 21:  3    10     7 0.8744985     3
> 22:  3    20     7 0.8744985    13
> 23:  3    30    36 0.4724253     6
> 24:  3    40    38 0.2016645     2
> 25:  3    50    51 0.2016645     1
> 26:  3    60    53 0.4750352     7
> 27:  3    70    53 0.4750352    17
> 28:  3    80    87 0.3202490     7
> 29:  3    90    91 0.8744985     1
> 30:  3   100    91 0.8744985     9
> 31:  4    10    10 0.2016645     0
> 32:  4    20    11 0.8744985     9
> 33:  4    30    11 0.8744985    19
> 34:  4    40    61 0.3202490    21
> 35:  4    50    61 0.3202490    11
> 36:  4    60    61 0.3202490     1
> 37:  4    70    72 0.4750352     2
> 38:  4    80    74 0.4724253     6
> 39:  4    90    92 0.3202490     2
> 40:  4   100    95 0.2016645     5
> 41:  5    10     3 0.3202490     7
> 42:  5    20    25 0.3202490     5
> 43:  5    30    31 0.2016645     1
> 44:  5    40    43 0.4724253     3
> 45:  5    50    51 0.2016645     1
> 46:  5    60    60 0.4724253     0
> 47:  5    70    62 0.4750352     8
> 48:  5    80    91 0.8744985    11
> 49:  5    90    91 0.8744985     1
> 50:  5   100    91 0.8744985     9
> ```

Comment: I don't mean to nitpick - i'm just learning `data.table` and am curious. Is there any reason to not include `delta = abs(x.loc - i.loc)` in the `j` argument of the first set of square brackets?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `data.table` so this may be a stupid question. Does `roll = "nearest"` apply to both `ID` and `loc`? For example, if `ID` is in `df` but not `df_alt` will it find the nearest `ID` in `df_alt`? Because that's not desirable. That is, `ID` has to be exact.

Comment: @Lyngbakr - it would only apply the last 'joined' column, `loc` in this case. There's a few more details at `?data.table` if you're curious.

Comment: @zack there isn't a reason for that; updated the answer now

Comment: @Jaap This is a great solution and I'm neck deep in the introductory material for `data.table` to try to understand it fully. Quick clarification: how could you retain all columns in both data tables without stating them individually within the `j` argument?

Comment: @Lyngbakr You could use `mget` for that, [see here for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37994369/2204410) on how to use `mget`.

Comment: And, for the record, not only does this solve the problem, but *man* it's fast!

Comment: @Lyngbakr That's exactly why I like the `data.table`-package so much :-)

Comment: @Jaap  I would reaallly like to use this code but I am having a little bit of trouble with adapting the syntax. The current solution, if I understand correctly, gives the columns mentioned in the `, .(ID, loc.x = i.loc, loc.y = x.loc, value, delta = abs(i.loc - x.loc))]` how could I change it to give be all columns of both datasets? In addition, I would like to change `roll` to `-1 | +1` (?data.table however says it or plus or minus or nearest). How would data.table accept this?

Comment: @Jaap I decided to make a question about it.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53931501/doing-a-fuzzyjoin-and-non-fuzzyjoin-in-combination-with-a-merge-in-data-tabl