# R: data.table: := in reverse case

Tags: r, performance, data.table, left-join

Suppose I have two datasets that I want to left-join,

```
i <- data.table(id=1:3, k=7:9, l=7:9, m=7:9, n=7:9)
```

and

```
x <- data.table(id=c(1,2), x=c(10,20))
```

To left-join, keeping all lines in `i`, I execute

```
x[i, .(id=i.id, k=i.k, l=i.l, m=i.m, n=i.n, x=x.x), on=.(id=id)]
```

but I wonder whether there is an easier and more efficient way that makes it unnecessary to spell out all the columns from `i`.

For example, in the reverse case (that is, when I want to keep all columns from `i`), I could use the `:=` operator, as in `x[i, k:=i.k, on=.(id=id)]`. My understanding is that this makes things also more efficient because columns do not need to be copied. Is there something comparable for this case?

Comment: Does the last part of [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37994369/2204410) help?

Comment: If it means that there is no such thing as a reverse-:=, it helps clarifying (but sadly means I need to find other ways to make it more efficient). Is this so?

Comment: Why not `i[x, on = .(id), x := i.x][]`? If I understand your question correctly, then that is what you are looking for.

Comment: This works (and saves 1/4 in time) but confuses me. My understanding was that the inner DF is the left one in a left-join. The one of which all rows are kept. Now I see that it also works the other way around, but only in `i[x, on = .(id), x := i.x]` , whereas `i[x, on = .(id)]` appears to perform an inner join. Is there any place where this is explained?

Comment: [Does this explanation help?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34600831/2204410)

Comment: Very helpful to understand the efficiency gain, but leaves me wondering why `i[x, on = .(id)]` does an inner-join, whereas `i[x, on = .(id), x := i.x]` does a left-join.

Comment: `i[x, on = .(id), x := i.x]` updates `i` by reference and look in `x` which rows match and thus need to be updated; whereas `i[x, on = .(id)]` also uses `x` but only give back the rows that match (because there isn't a need to update something)

Comment: This helps to know, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

you can use data-tables `setcolorder()` after the join..

```
setcolorder( x[i, on = "id"], c( names(i), "x" ) )

#    id k l m n  x
# 1:  1 7 7 7 7 10
# 2:  2 8 8 8 8 20
# 3:  3 9 9 9 9 NA
```

Comment: Thanks, but this was mostly about the efficiency.

Comment: @bumblebee `setcolorder` changes the order of the data.table 'by reference' (same as `:=` does), so it is pretty darn efficient :)

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with merge?

```
  y <- merge(i, x, all.x = TRUE, by = "id")
```

Comment: Nothing wrong but my point was about the efficiency of `:='. Thanks, anyway!