# Replacing values in a column where there is a match

Tags: r, dataframe, match

I'm new to R programming and I'm stuck on the example below.

Basically I have two data sets:

dataset1:

```
ID       Category        
1        CatZZ         
2        CatVV         
3        CatAA  
4        CatQQ
```

dataset2:

```
ID  Category  
1   Cat600  
3   Cat611
```

I'm trying to overwrite the 'category' values in dataset1 with the 'category' values in dataset2 where there is an ID match between the two data sets.

So the outcome would look something like this:

dataset1:

```
ID  Category    
1   Cat600  
2   CatVV  
3   Cat611  
4   CatQQ
```

Answer (score 3):

In `tidyverse` you can do:

```
df1 %>%
 left_join(df2, by = c("ID" = "ID")) %>% #Merging the two dfs on ID
 mutate(Category = if_else(!is.na(Category.y), Category.y, Category.x)) %>% #If there is a match, taking the value from df2, otherwise from df1
 select(ID, Category) #Deleting the redundant variables

  ID Category
1  1   Cat600
2  2    CatVV
3  3   Cat611
4  4    CatQQ
```

Or:

```
df1 %>%
 left_join(df2, by = c("ID" = "ID")) %>% #Merging the two dfs on ID
 gather(var, val, -ID) %>% #Transforming the data from wide to long format
 arrange(ID) %>% #Arranging by ID
 group_by(ID) %>% #Grouping by ID
 mutate(Category = if_else(!is.na(nth(val, 2)), nth(val, 2), first(val))) %>% #If non-NA, taking the value from df2, otherwise from df1
 spread(var, val) %>% #Returning the data to wide format
 select(ID, Category) #Removing the redundant variables 

     ID Category
  <int> <chr>   
1     1 Cat600  
2     2 CatVV   
3     3 Cat611  
4     4 CatQQ
```

Sample data:

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "ID       Category        
1        CatZZ         
2        CatVV         
3        CatAA  
4        CatQQ", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df2 <- read.table(text = "ID  Category  
1   Cat600  
                  3   Cat611", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use `data.table` package.

Using the same setup as @tmfmnk in his answer:

**Construct the sample data set:**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "ID       Category        
1        CatZZ         
2        CatVV         
3        CatAA  
4        CatQQ", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df2 <- read.table(text = "ID  Category  
1   Cat600  
                  3   Cat611", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

**Load the `data.table` package and convert dataframes to data tables:**

```
library(data.table)
df1 <- data.table(df1)
df2 <- data.table(df2)
```

**Perform a left join**

(take all values from df1, where ID matches with df2, and add there the category from df2, then create a new column combining info from df1 and df2)

```
a <- df2[df1, on = "ID"][, a := ifelse(is.na(Category), i.Category, Category)]
```

There is a nice question and answer on data.table joins here: [Left join using data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34598139/left-join-using-data-table/34600831)

Also, to get exactly the result you asked for, you can do:

```
a <- df2[df1, on = "ID"][, list(ID, Category = ifelse(is.na(Category), i.Category, Category))]
```

Comment: It's better to use an 'update'-join: `df1[df2, on = .(ID), Category := i.Category]`, which is more memory efficient (see also [the updated benchmark here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34600831/2204410)).

Answer (score 2):

Using a combination of base R `match` function and data.table's `set` function:

```
matchinds = na.omit(match(dataset1$ID,dataset2$ID)) # this will give index of dataset2$ID where values of dataset1$ID were equal to values of dataset2$ID

set(x=dataset1,i=matchinds,j="Category",value=dataset2$category[matchinds])  #this will set values at matching indexes in dataset1 Category column equal to Category column matching index values in dataset2
```

Answer (score 2):

A `base R` approach that uses `match`

```
df1$Category[match(df2$ID, df1$ID)] <- df2$Category
df1
#  ID Category
#1  1   Cat600
#2  2    CatVV
#3  3   Cat611
#4  4    CatQQ
```

**data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:4, Category = c("CatZZ", "CatVV", "CatAA", 
"CatQQ")), .Names = c("ID", "Category"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

df2 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 3L), Category = c("Cat600", "Cat611"
)), .Names = c("ID", "Category"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can stack `df2` on top of `df1` and keep the first instance for each `ID`.

With *`tidyverse`* that would be :

```
library(tidyverse)
bind_rows(df2,df1) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 4 x 2
#      ID Category
#   <int>    <chr>
# 1     1   Cat600
# 2     2    CatVV
# 3     3   Cat611
# 4     4    CatQQ
```

Or a base version (which reorders the rows) :

```
subset(rbind(df2,df1), !duplicated(ID))
#   ID Category
# 1  1   Cat600
# 2  3   Cat611
# 4  2    CatVV
# 6  4    CatQQ
```