# How to set the values of a column in an R data.table by referring the key and values in a second data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose I have a data.table in R:

```
> A=data.table(Col1=c(1,4,2,5,6,2,3,5,3,7))
> A
    Col1
 1:    1
 2:    4
 3:    2
 4:    5
 5:    6
 6:    2
 7:    3
 8:    5
 9:    3
10:    7
```

And a key-value data.table where

```
> B=data.table(Col1=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),Col2=c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G"))
> B
   Col1 Col2
1:    1    A
2:    2    B
3:    3    C
4:    4    D
5:    5    E
6:    6    F
7:    7    G
```

I would like to have `Col1` of data.table `A` reference `B` and create a new column in `A` that corresponds to the key-value pairs:

```
    Col1 Col2
 1:    1    A
 2:    4    D
 3:    2    B
 4:    5    E
 5:    6    F
 6:    2    B
 7:    3    C
 8:    5    E
 9:    3    C
10:    7    G
```

How can I do this in data.table? Thanks

Comment: Look at `?merge`

Comment: You want to do an update join. Study the package vignettes.

Comment: I really feel like this is a dupe of Shree's link, but none of those answers really demonstrate the merge-assignment of Wimpel's answer (e.g., `A[B, Col2 := i.Col2, on = .(Col1)]`). Here's (perhaps) a more canonical link: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34598139/3358272

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is a join by reference/update join.

This looks for the value of A$Col1 in B$Col1, **and returns the first match** of B$Col2 (so if there are >1 matches, the value returned depends on how B is ordered). In the code, this is referred as `i.Col2`, since B is in the `i`-part of the data.table syntax. It is usually the fastest way to join, but remember that it only returns the first match. SO if there are multiple values of B$Col2 fot the same B$Col1 value, you will only get one (the topmost) value returned.

```
A[B, Col2 := i.Col2, on = .(Col1)]

    Col1 Col2
 1:    1    A
 2:    4    D
 3:    2    B
 4:    5    E
 5:    6    F
 6:    2    B
 7:    3    C
 8:    5    E
 9:    3    C
10:    7    G
```

Answer (score -1):

Using `data.table`s `on` argument

```
library(data.table)

A[B, , on = "Col1"]
    Col1 Col2
 1:    1    A
 2:    2    B
 3:    2    B
 4:    3    C
 5:    3    C
 6:    4    D
 7:    5    E
 8:    5    E
 9:    6    F
10:    7    G
```