# Filter by group using column from another dataframe but keep grouping information in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a large dataframe that I would like to filter by another dataframe column but keep the grouping information to inform the filtering. I want to filter by the ID column but use the year column to inform the grouping with the other dataframe. In my current example the `group_by` call does not work across dataframes since I am filtering by only one column. Keep in mind that I want this to be a more general expression that I can use on a dataset with hundreds of thousands of rows, so explicitly writing out all the potential filtering combinations of year and ID would not be practical. Here is my example:

```
df_filter<-data.frame(year=c(20,20,20,21,21,21),ID=seq(1:6))

df_all<-data.frame(year=c(20,20,20,21,21,21), ID=c(1,2,4,3,5,6))

filtered<-df_all %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  filter(ID %in% df_filter$ID)

> filtered
   year    ID
1    20     1
2    20     2
3    20     4
4    21     3
5    21     5
6    21     6

***desired result***
   year    ID
1    20     1
2    20     2
3    21     5
4    21     6
```

Thanks!

Comment: This is a merge/join operation, you can learn more about it at https://stackoverflow.com/q/1299871/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/5706437/3358272, and https://stackoverflow.com/q/34598139/3358272

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `dplyr::semi_join()`:

```
library(dplyr)

semi_join(df_all, df_filter)
```

```
# Joining with `by = join_by(year, ID)`
  year ID
1   20  1
2   20  2
3   21  5
4   21  6
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `merge` from *base*.

```
merge(df_all, df_filter)
#  year ID
#1   20  1
#2   20  2
#3   21  5
#4   21  6
```