# call a function and return result to existing data frame

Tags: r

```
## Import airport data
airports <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jpatokal/openflights/master/data/airports.dat", header = F)


library(geosphere)
## Calculate matrix of differences in km
distance.matrix <- distm(x = airports[,c("V8", "V7")],  y = airports[,c("V8", "V7")])/1000
## This may take a while, and will generate a matrix 8107 by 8107, about 0.5gb in size.

## Rename dimensions to airport codes
rownames(distance.matrix) <- airports$V5
colnames(distance.matrix) <- airports$V5

## Example: km between Gatwick and Heathrow
distance.matrix['LGW', 'LHR']

al_route <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jpatokal/openflights/master/data/routes.dat", header = F)
#Example 2B,410,LGW,2965,LHR,2990,0,CR2
```

I am trying to pass 4th column (LGW) and 6th column (LHR) of each row in al_route and add the result (distance btw LGW and LHR) to the new column of al_route.  I am having trouble figuring out, I would expect my al_route will be like

```
v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7, v8, v9 (new col)
2B,410,LGW,2965,LHR,2990,0,CR2, distance
```

Comment: Other than `V8`, all columns are strings. Try `grep("\\D", al_route$V4)` to see how many rows have a non-number in the `V4` field, and then `al_route[39 + -2:2,]` (where `39` is the first when I ran it) to see that `al_route$V4[39]` is the string `\N` (and in fact all non-number `V4` are the same).

Comment: You need to [merge/join](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1299871/3358272) (also https://stackoverflow.com/q/5706437/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/34598139/3358272) the lat/lon from your `airports` object into your `al_routes` data. I suggest before you go too far that you name your columns, keeping them the obscure `V#` names will drive you crazy and open you up to many ways of "off-by-one".

Answer (score 0):

You need to *merge/join* your data so that you can get the longitude/latitude from `airports` into your `al_route` frame. For guidance on this, see [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1299871/3358272), [What's the difference between INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN and FULL JOIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5706437/3358272), (data.table) [Left join using data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34598139/3358272).

To really do all of this right, though, we need to fix a couple of other things here. All together:

1. Name your columns using https://openflights.org/data. It is certainly possible to go without this step, but not doing so really opens you up to choosing incorrect columns for something.
2. Fix the `airports` ID field (column 1), it should be character (to match the `al_route` source/dest airport IDs) but is loaded as integer.
3. Merge/join the data. *Twice*, once to get the lon/lat of the source airport, once for the destination.
4. Do the calc, but ... don't use `distm`, it will calculate every possible distance between ever set of pairs in the whole frame. On my system with 64GB of RAM, it crashed me hard due to the over-allocation of memory. You only want row-wise distances (which R and `geosphere` do quickly/efficiently in a vectorized fashion), so we'll switch from `distm` to `distHaversine`. (If you want more accurate, there's also `distVincentyEllipsoid`. If you don't know the difference, it's really unlikely you'll need it.)

## Base R

Steps:

```r
# 0. Download
airports <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jpatokal/openflights/master/data/airports.dat", header = F)
al_route <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jpatokal/openflights/master/data/routes.dat", header = F)

# 1. Name them
names(airports) <- c("AirportID", "Name", "City", "Country", "IATA", "ICAO", "Lat", "Lon", "Alt", "Timezone", "DST", "Tz", "Type", "Source")
names(al_route) <- c("Airline", "AirlineID", "S_Airport", "S_AirportID", "D_Airport", "D_AirportID", "Codeshare", "Stops", "Equipment")

# 2. Ints to strings
airports$AirportID <- as.character(airports$AirportID)

# 3. Merge/join and 4. Calculate the distance between source/dest airports.
al_route <- al_route |>
  merge(setNames(airports[, c("AirportID", "Lon", "Lat")], c("S_AirportID", "S_Lon", "S_Lat")),
        by = "S_AirportID", all.x = TRUE, sort = FALSE) |>
  merge(setNames(airports[, c("AirportID", "Lon", "Lat")], c("D_AirportID", "D_Lon", "D_Lat")),
        by = "D_AirportID", all.x = TRUE, sort = FALSE) |>
  transform(Dist = geosphere::distHaversine(cbind(S_Lon, S_Lat), cbind(D_Lon, D_Lat)))
head(al_route)
#   D_AirportID S_AirportID Airline AirlineID S_Airport D_Airport Codeshare Stops Equipment    S_Lon    S_Lat   D_Lon   D_Lat      Dist
# 1        3964        2975      QN       426       SVX       EVN               0       735 60.80270 56.74310 44.3959 40.1473 2196701.4
# 2        3964        2975      U6      5234       SVX       EVN               0       320 60.80270 56.74310 44.3959 40.1473 2196701.4
# 3        3964        2964      SU       130       ROV       EVN               0       319 39.92472 47.49389 44.3959 40.1473  892801.9
# 4        3964        1613      UA      5209       VIE       EVN         Y     0   320 321 16.56970 48.11030 44.3959 40.1473 2377245.8
# 5        3964        4078      S7      4329       OVB       EVN               0       320 82.65070 55.01260 44.3959 40.1473 3257169.1
# 6        3964        4330      EP      2923       IKA       EVN               0       100 51.15220 35.41610 44.3959 40.1473  793735.0
```

The results are in meters.

## dplyr

(After naming and int-to-string.)

```r
library(dplyr)
al_route <- tibble(al_route) %>%
  left_join(select(airports, S_AirportID = AirportID, S_Lon = Lon, S_Lat = Lat), by = "S_AirportID") %>%
  left_join(select(airports, D_AirportID = AirportID, D_Lon = Lon, D_Lat = Lat), by = "D_AirportID") %>%
  mutate(Dist = geosphere::distHaversine(cbind(S_Lon, S_Lat), cbind(D_Lon, D_Lat)))
```

Comment: many thanks for your help !!! r2evans.  much appreciated!!!