# Conditional matching between data frames of different length (if two values from df1 are in df2, take a value from df2)

Tags: r, loops, merge, conditional-statements, match

I have two dataframes and df1 is shorter than df2. There are two values that overlap (repeatedly) between the two dataframes. By row, if "Listener" in df1 matches a "Listener" row in df2 **and** "Trial" in df1 matches a "Trial" row in df2, take "PercCor" from df2 and put it in df1.

The vectors are rather long (df1 is 147200 rows and df2 is 510000) so that's some of my trouble.

Here's a sample dataset that might help illuminate the problem, I hope.

```
df1 <- data.frame(Listener = c("01JA","01JA","02JK","02JK", "03GL", "03GL"), Trial = c("Trial 1", "Trial 2", "Trial 1", "Trial 2", "Trial 1", "Trial 2"),
                  Pupil = c(1,2,4,3,2,6), Time = c(20, 40, 20, 40, 20, 40), percCor = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA))
df2 <- data.frame(Listener = c("01JA","01JA","01JA","01JA", "01JA", "02JK","02JK","02JK","02JK", "02JK", "03GL", "03GL","03GL", "03GL", "03GL"), 
                 Trial = c("Trial 1", "Trial 1", "Trial 2", "Trial 2", "Trial 3","Trial 1", "Trial 1", "Trial 2", "Trial 2", "Trial 3","Trial 1", "Trial 1", "Trial 2", "Trial 2", "Trial 3"),
                 Pupil = c(1,1,1,2,4,3,2,6,2,5,6,2,4,5,6), Time = c(50, 100, 150, 50, 100, 150,50, 100, 150, 50, 100, 150, 50, 100, 150), percCor = c(100, 100, 20, 20, 60, 60, 60, 30, 30, 40, 60, 60, 40, 40, 55))
```

The answer I'm looking for is:

```
dfans <- data.framedf1 <- data.frame(Listener = c("01JA","01JA","02JK","02JK", "03GL", "03GL"), Trial = c("Trial 1", "Trial 2", "Trial 1", "Trial 2", "Trial 1", "Trial 2"),
                                     Pupil = c(1,2,4,3,2,6), Time = c(20, 40, 20, 40, 20, 40), percCor = c(100, 20, 60, 30, 60, 40))
```

I've tried the following solutions but run into issues with each. I seem to be lacking the knowledge to evaluate two expressions at once. I also tried a data.table solution but kept getting the syntax wrong - I'm not very familiar with it :(

```
mdf <- merge(x=df1,y=df2, by.x=c("Listener","Trial"), by.y=c("Listener","Trial"))
#not enough RAM

mdf<-left_join(df1, df2, by= c('Listener','Trial'))%>%
   mutate(percCor=percCor.y)%>%
   select(-c(percCor.x,percCor.y))
#not enough RAM

mdf <-left_join(df1, df2)
#doesn't capture percCor

mdf <-right_join(df1, df2)
#keeps unnecessary trials/data

for(id in 1:nrow(df2)){
  df1$percCor[df1$Listener %in% df2$Listener[id]] <- df2$percCor[id]
}
#doesn't evaluate both Trial and Listener and is slow. 

for(id in 1:nrow(df2)){
  df1$percCor[df1$Listener %in% df2$Listener[id] & df1$Trial %in% df2$Trial] <- df2$percCor[id]
}
#not entirely sure why it seems to not evaluate both expressions at the same time. It only takes the listener's last percCor value for all trials. It's also incredibly slow.
```

Help? This feels like something I should know how to do... but I'm very self-taught with R and honestly pretty much a newbie even though I've used it for a few projects. I'm guessing this won't be that difficult - I've spent half a week looking through stackoverflow answers - so I apologize if this is obvious.

Thank you for taking a look!

Comment: This is a merge/join operation, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/1299871/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/5706437/3358272, (data.table) https://stackoverflow.com/q/34598139/3358272. **However**, this produces 1+ rows for each in `df1`: for example, in `df2`, there are two rows that match `01JA` and `Trial 1`, which of its two `percCor` should be used? max/min/first/last/random?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Just to be clear on the logic: If a row in `df1` has a `Listener` value and a `Trial` value that both match the same row in `df2`, take `PercCor` from that row in `df2` - right?  Is there any possibility of duplicates? (>1 row in `df2` matches a combination of `Listener` and `Trial`?)

Comment: FYI, *"not enough RAM"* ... perhaps `data.table` is your only _local_ option for constrained memory operations, but you need to address the duplicate nature mentioned in the first two comments.

Comment: Hi - thank you! Yes, 'df2' will have multiple rows of '01JA' and 'Trial 1' that will match multiple rows in 'df1' of '01JA' and 'Trial 2'. I should have been clearer: all instances of '01JA' and 'Trial 2' in 'df2' will always have the same percCor value, so min/max/first/last/random will all be the same value.

'df2' has 17 instances of 'Listener' and each listener has 80 instances of 'Trial'. The unique combination of the two together will always have the same 'percCor' value. I hope that's clear :)
@r2evans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are explicitly ignoring some fields from `df2` that are producing multiple rows. For instance, looking at just the first row of `df1`, we see:

```r
merge(df1[1,], df2, by = c("Listener", "Trial"), all.x = TRUE, suffix = c("", ".y"))
#   Listener   Trial Pupil Time percCor Pupil.y Time.y percCor.y
# 1     01JA Trial 1     1   20      NA       1     50       100
# 2     01JA Trial 1     1   20      NA       1    100       100
```

Looking at this (and the others), the `percCor.y` is invariant, suggesting that you don't care about `Pupil` or `Time`, so we can reduce `df2` before going there.

Perhaps:

```r
merge(df1, unique(df2[, c("Listener", "Trial", "percCor")]), by = c("Listener", "Trial"), all.x = TRUE, suffix = c("", ".y")) |>
  transform(percCor = ifelse(is.na(percCor), percCor.y, percCor)) |>
  subset(select = -percCor.y)
#   Listener   Trial Pupil Time percCor
# 1     01JA Trial 1     1   20     100
# 2     01JA Trial 2     2   40      20
# 3     02JK Trial 1     4   20      60
# 4     02JK Trial 2     3   40      30
# 5     03GL Trial 1     2   20      60
# 6     03GL Trial 2     6   40      40
```

I am assuming that `percCor` *may* have valid values before the join, requiring the coalescing/`ifelse`-ing of the values. If this is not the case, then remove it before the join and no need for the `ifelse` (or `coalesce` below).

Variants:

```r
### dplyr
library(dplyr)
df2 %>%
  distinct(Listener, Trial, percCor) %>%
  right_join(df1, by = c("Listener", "Trial"), suffix = c(".y", "")) %>%
  mutate(percCor = coalesce(percCor, percCor.y)) %>%
  select(-percCor.y)
#   Listener   Trial Pupil Time percCor
# 1     01JA Trial 1     1   20     100
# 2     01JA Trial 2     2   40      20
# 3     02JK Trial 1     4   20      60
# 4     02JK Trial 2     3   40      30
# 5     03GL Trial 1     2   20      60
# 6     03GL Trial 2     6   40      40

### data.table
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)
df1[unique(df2, by = c("Listener", "Trial", "percCor")),
    percCor.y := i.percCor, on = .(Listener, Trial)
  ][, percCor := fcoalesce(as.numeric(percCor), as.numeric(percCor.y))
  ][, percCor.y := NULL][]
#    Listener   Trial Pupil  Time percCor
#      <char>  <char> <num> <num>   <num>
# 1:     01JA Trial 1     1    20     100
# 2:     01JA Trial 2     2    40      20
# 3:     02JK Trial 1     4    20      60
# 4:     02JK Trial 2     3    40      30
# 5:     03GL Trial 1     2    20      60
# 6:     03GL Trial 2     6    40      40
```

The use of `as.numeric(.)` is because `fcoalesce` is very strict about *class-safety*, something that `ifelse` has always done poorly at, and `dplyr::if_else` has recently relaxed (not a great thing imho).

Notes about `data.table`: if you never have `percCor` filled in `df1` first, then you can just do `percCor := i.percCor` in the initial join and skip the `fcoalesce` and cleanup steps.

Comment: Thank you! I'm at work right now and a patient just showed up... so I'll have to try this in a bit. But I really appreciate your help! :)

Comment: Beautiful, thank you so much. The data.table worked brilliantly with my larger dataset and is quick and efficient. I really appreciate you helping me with this! @r2evans