# Merging two datasets with some identical columns

Tags: r

I need help doing something that should be simple in R.
I have two datasets: mem, and birds.
I need to merge these two datasets, but sum the columns that are identical from both datasets. I need an output that includes the unique columns from mem, birds, and the columns that are identical from the two datasets added together:
Notice how 3z is shared by both datasets.

I also want to substitue all Na's with 0's.
I've been trying to do this in R but keep encountering errors. Any help is appreciated!

```
birds   1a  2c  3z  4x          
    1   10  0   10  10          
    2   2   0   2   4           
    3   4   0   13  0           
    4   2   2   1   0           
    5   0   0   0   0           
                                
                                
    mem 13a 7x  3z  6z          
    6   8   7   11  1           
    7   0   0   2   7           
    8   3   0   1   8           
    9   2   3   1   0           
    10  1   0   1   0           
  Desired                           
 output 1a  2c  3z  4x  13a 7x  6z
    1   10  0   10  10  0   0   0
    2   2   0   2   4   0   0   0
    3   4   0   13  0   0   0   0
    4   2   2   1   0   0   0   0
    5   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    6   0   0   11  0   8   7   1
    7   0   0   2   0   0   0   7
    8   0   0   1   0   3   0   8
    9   0   0   1   0   2   3   0
    10  0   0   1   0   1   0   0
```

Comment: Two questions: (1) there do not appear to be any  NAs in either `birds` or `mom`, so what do you with to make 0? And (2) is `output` your *desired* outcome? Asking (2) in order to determine your intent regarding "sum the columns that are identical". Thanks!

Comment: FYI, the term "merge" (and similarly R's function `merge`) is generally associated with the SQL-borne notion of merge/join, combining data based on shared ID fields. Not a problem for this question, but know that asking to "merge" data can have very different meanings to different people. I think for this data you're looking to combine (row-wise) two frames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FYI, the term "merge" (and similarly R's function `base::merge`) is generally associated with the SQL-borne notion of merge/join, combining data based on shared ID fields (see some links at the bottom of this answer). Not a problem for this question, but know that asking to "merge" data can have very different meanings to different people. I think for this data you're looking to combine (row-wise) two frames. This can be done using `base::rbind` (with a bit of effort) or `dplyr::bind_rows` (zero effort) or `data.table::rbindlist` (barely any effort).

For all three dialects, the need to have `0` in missing cells takes just a little more work.

## dplyr

`bind_rows` is very accommodating with regards to names, location, and data types (though it will still warn in some cases).

```r
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(birds, mem) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ coalesce(., 0)))
#    1a 2c 3z 4x 13a 7x 6z
# 1  10  0 10 10   0  0  0
# 2   2  0  2  4   0  0  0
# 3   4  0 13  0   0  0  0
# 4   2  2  1  0   0  0  0
# 5   0  0  0  0   0  0  0
# 6   0  0 11  0   8  7  1
# 7   0  0  2  0   0  0  7
# 8   0  0  1  0   3  0  8
# 9   0  0  1  0   2  3  0
# 10  0  0  1  0   1  0  0
```

## base R

We need to handle not only the location but also the *presence* of all names manually. It's not super-slow and can be automated a little, if desired.

```r
nms <- unique(c(names(birds), names(mem)))
lapply(list(birds, mem), function(X)
    cbind(X[,intersect(names(X), nms)], 
          data.frame(lapply(setNames(nm = setdiff(nms, names(X))), function(Z) 0), check.names = FALSE))[,nms]
) |>
  do.call(rbind, args = _)
#    1a 2c 3z 4x 13a 7x 6z
# 1  10  0 10 10   0  0  0
# 2   2  0  2  4   0  0  0
# 3   4  0 13  0   0  0  0
# 4   2  2  1  0   0  0  0
# 5   0  0  0  0   0  0  0
# 6   0  0 11  0   8  7  1
# 7   0  0  2  0   0  0  7
# 8   0  0  1  0   3  0  8
# 9   0  0  1  0   2  3  0
# 10  0  0  1  0   1  0  0


lapply(list(birds, mem), 
  function(X) data.frame(lapply(setNames(nm = nms),
                                function(nm) if (nm %in% names(X)) X[[nm]] else 0), 
                         check.names = FALSE)
) |>
  do.call(rbind.data.frame, args = _)
#    1a 2c 3z 4x 13a 7x 6z
# 1  10  0 10 10   0  0  0
# 2   2  0  2  4   0  0  0
# 3   4  0 13  0   0  0  0
# 4   2  2  1  0   0  0  0
# 5   0  0  0  0   0  0  0
# 6   0  0 11  0   8  7  1
# 7   0  0  2  0   0  0  7
# 8   0  0  1  0   3  0  8
# 9   0  0  1  0   2  3  0
# 10  0  0  1  0   1  0  0
```

## data.table

`rbindlist` is a little more strict in the notion that we must explicitly tell it to join by-name and also not by-position. It's not hard, just a couple of arguments.

```r
library(data.table)
# because `fcoalesce` is very particular about 0 vs 0L
zero <- function(z) if (is.integer(z)) 0L else 0
rbindlist(list(birds, mem), use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE
  )[, lapply(.SD, function(z) fcoalesce(z, zero(z)))]
#        1a    2c    3z    4x   13a    7x    6z
#     <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#  1:    10     0    10    10     0     0     0
#  2:     2     0     2     4     0     0     0
#  3:     4     0    13     0     0     0     0
#  4:     2     2     1     0     0     0     0
#  5:     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
#  6:     0     0    11     0     8     7     1
#  7:     0     0     2     0     0     0     7
#  8:     0     0     1     0     3     0     8
#  9:     0     0     1     0     2     3     0
# 10:     0     0     1     0     1     0     0
```

---

Data

```r
birds <- structure(list("1a" = c(10L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 0L), "2c" = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L), "3z" = c(10L, 2L, 13L, 1L, 0L), "4x" = c(10L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"))
mem <- structure(list("13a" = c(8L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 1L), "7x" = c(7L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L), "3z" = c(11L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), "6z" = c(1L, 7L, 8L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```

---

<sub>Concepts of merge/join, though I believe not relevant to this question: [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1299871/3358272), [What's the difference between INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN and FULL JOIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5706437/3358272), (data.table) [Left join using data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34598139/3358272).</sub>

Comment: Hi there, eventhough I have checked the structure of both dataframes, I get an error that item 2 is type double. Why? I am following along with the following:zero <- function(z) if (is.integer(z)) 0L else 0

rbindlist(list(birds, mem,leaves), use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE
  )[, lapply(.SD, function(z) fcoalesce(z, zero(z)))]