# How to create a column within a data.table in R that filters the original data table and returns some value based on a condition

Tags: r, data.table

I have a rather large data.table and I would like to create a new column that searches for different rows of the same data.table based on a filter defined in the current row.

See example below:

```
library(data.table)
dt<-data.table(a=seq.Date(as.Date("2023-11-01"), as.Date("2023-11-30"), by="day"), 
               b=c(1:27, 46, 34, 101))
dt$a_m1<-c(seq.Date(as.Date("2023-11-16"), as.Date("2023-11-30"), by="day"), seq.Date(as.Date("2023-11-01"), as.Date("2023-11-15"), by="day"))

            a  b       a_m1
 1: 2023-11-01  1 2023-11-16
 2: 2023-11-02  2 2023-11-17
 3: 2023-11-03  3 2023-11-18
 4: 2023-11-04  4 2023-11-19
 5: 2023-11-05  5 2023-11-20
 6: 2023-11-06  6 2023-11-21
 7: 2023-11-07  7 2023-11-22
 8: 2023-11-08  8 2023-11-23
 9: 2023-11-09  9 2023-11-24
10: 2023-11-10 10 2023-11-25
11: 2023-11-11 11 2023-11-26
12: 2023-11-12 12 2023-11-27
13: 2023-11-13 13 2023-11-28
14: 2023-11-14 14 2023-11-29
15: 2023-11-15 15 2023-11-30
16: 2023-11-16 16 2023-11-01
17: 2023-11-17 17 2023-11-02
18: 2023-11-18 18 2023-11-03
19: 2023-11-19 19 2023-11-04
20: 2023-11-20 20 2023-11-05
21: 2023-11-21 21 2023-11-06
22: 2023-11-22 22 2023-11-07
23: 2023-11-23 23 2023-11-08
24: 2023-11-24 24 2023-11-09
25: 2023-11-25 25 2023-11-10
26: 2023-11-26 26 2023-11-11
27: 2023-11-27 27 2023-11-12
28: 2023-11-28 46 2023-11-13
29: 2023-11-29 34 2023-11-14
30: 2023-11-30 101 2023-11-15
```

The desired output would be:

```
             a  b       a_m1 b_m1
 1: 2023-11-01  1 2023-11-16   16
 2: 2023-11-02  2 2023-11-17   17
 3: 2023-11-03  3 2023-11-18   18
 4: 2023-11-04  4 2023-11-19   19
 5: 2023-11-05  5 2023-11-20   20
 6: 2023-11-06  6 2023-11-21   21
 7: 2023-11-07  7 2023-11-22   22
 8: 2023-11-08  8 2023-11-23   23
 9: 2023-11-09  9 2023-11-24   24
10: 2023-11-10 10 2023-11-25   25
11: 2023-11-11 11 2023-11-26   26
12: 2023-11-12 12 2023-11-27   27
13: 2023-11-13 13 2023-11-28   46
14: 2023-11-14 14 2023-11-29   34
15: 2023-11-15 15 2023-11-30   101
16: 2023-11-16 16 2023-11-01    1
17: 2023-11-17 17 2023-11-02    2
18: 2023-11-18 18 2023-11-03    3
19: 2023-11-19 19 2023-11-04    4
20: 2023-11-20 20 2023-11-05    5
21: 2023-11-21 21 2023-11-06    6
22: 2023-11-22 22 2023-11-07    7
23: 2023-11-23 23 2023-11-08    8
24: 2023-11-24 24 2023-11-09    9
25: 2023-11-25 25 2023-11-10   10
26: 2023-11-26 26 2023-11-11   11
27: 2023-11-27 27 2023-11-12   12
28: 2023-11-28 46 2023-11-13   13
29: 2023-11-29 34 2023-11-14   14
30: 2023-11-30 101 2023-11-15   15
```

Help with this would be much appreciated.
I have tried code like the following:

```
dt[,b_m1:=dt[a_m1==dt$a]$b,]
```

But to no avail.

Comment: `dt[, b_m1 := format(a_m1, "%d"), ]`

Comment: Hi @Friede while this does produce the desired output, it is calculated from ```a_m1```. You noticed that the day in ```a_m1``` matches the value in ```b_m1``` but that is not necessarily the case in my actual use case. So this won't generalise.

Comment: It works on your toy data and produces the desired output. If you want something else, then provide correspinding details. In other words, neither the data example nor the demonstration of the desired output is accurate.

Comment: It is accurate, you're just choosing to take a short cut, one that won't generalise. But as you wish, I edited the toy data set.

Comment: *create a new column that searches for different rows of the same data.table based on a filter defined in the current row.* I don't understand. Furthermore, I do not understand the data/desired result. Sorry, cannot help.

Comment: I agree a little with @Friede that it is encumbent on you to adjust your sample data when suggested code misses the intent, and it sometimes means you might need to explain your need in a different way. For instance, for this, *"filter defined in the current row"* provides insufficient detail, and assuming that your offered code would explain what you really need is not a safe assumption. Having said that, I'm guessing from your code that you need a self-join; if I'm wrong, then I think it would help if you expanded on the conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a self-join assignment.

```r
dt[dt, b_m1 := i.b, on = .(a == a_m1)]
#              a     b       a_m1  b_m1
#         <Date> <num>     <Date> <num>
#  1: 2023-11-01     1 2023-11-16    16
#  2: 2023-11-02     2 2023-11-17    17
#  3: 2023-11-03     3 2023-11-18    18
#  4: 2023-11-04     4 2023-11-19    19
#  5: 2023-11-05     5 2023-11-20    20
#  6: 2023-11-06     6 2023-11-21    21
#  7: 2023-11-07     7 2023-11-22    22
#  8: 2023-11-08     8 2023-11-23    23
#  9: 2023-11-09     9 2023-11-24    24
# 10: 2023-11-10    10 2023-11-25    25
# ---                                  
# 21: 2023-11-21    21 2023-11-06     6
# 22: 2023-11-22    22 2023-11-07     7
# 23: 2023-11-23    23 2023-11-08     8
# 24: 2023-11-24    24 2023-11-09     9
# 25: 2023-11-25    25 2023-11-10    10
# 26: 2023-11-26    26 2023-11-11    11
# 27: 2023-11-27    27 2023-11-12    12
# 28: 2023-11-28    46 2023-11-13    13
# 29: 2023-11-29    34 2023-11-14    14
# 30: 2023-11-30   101 2023-11-15    15

all.equal(dt, desired)
# [1] TRUE
```

In general this is a merge/join, and a good `data.table`-specific Q/A here on StackOverflow is [Left join using data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34598139/3358272). For the concept in more general terms, see

- [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1299871/3358272)
- [What's the difference between INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN and FULL JOIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5706437/3358272)

---

Data:

```r
# calculated from the question
dt <- data.table::as.data.table(structure(list(a = structure(c(19662, 19663, 19664, 19665, 19666, 19667, 19668, 19669, 19670, 19671, 19672, 19673, 19674, 19675, 19676, 19677, 19678, 19679, 19680, 19681, 19682, 19683, 19684, 19685, 19686, 19687, 19688, 19689, 19690, 19691), class = "Date"), b = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 46, 34, 101), a_m1 = structure(c(19677, 19678, 19679, 19680, 19681, 19682, 19683, 19684, 19685, 19686, 19687, 19688, 19689, 19690, 19691,  19662, 19663, 19664, 19665, 19666, 19667, 19668, 19669, 19670, 19671, 19672, 19673, 19674, 19675, 19676), class = "Date"), b_m1 = c(16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 46, 34, 101, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15)), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame")))
# copied and Date-ified from the question text
desired <- data.table::as.data.table(structure(list(a = structure(c(19662, 19663, 19664, 19665, 19666, 19667, 19668, 19669, 19670, 19671, 19672, 19673, 19674, 19675, 19676, 19677, 19678, 19679, 19680, 19681, 19682, 19683, 19684, 19685, 19686, 19687, 19688, 19689, 19690, 19691), class = "Date"), b = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 46L, 34L, 101L), a_m1 = structure(c(19677, 19678, 19679, 19680, 19681, 19682, 19683, 19684, 19685, 19686, 19687,  19688, 19689, 19690, 19691, 19662, 19663, 19664, 19665, 19666, 19667, 19668, 19669, 19670, 19671, 19672, 19673, 19674, 19675, 19676), class = "Date"), b_m1 = c(16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 46L, 34L, 101L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L)), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame")))
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you @r2evans for your help!

Answer (score 1):

you can also solve your problem as follow:

```
dt[, b_m1 := b[match(a, a_m1)]]

             a     b       a_m1  b_m1
 1: 2023-11-01     1 2023-11-16    16
 2: 2023-11-02     2 2023-11-17    17
 3: 2023-11-03     3 2023-11-18    18
 4: 2023-11-04     4 2023-11-19    19
 5: 2023-11-05     5 2023-11-20    20
 6: 2023-11-06     6 2023-11-21    21
 7: 2023-11-07     7 2023-11-22    22
----
23: 2023-11-23    23 2023-11-08     8
24: 2023-11-24    24 2023-11-09     9
25: 2023-11-25    25 2023-11-10    10
26: 2023-11-26    26 2023-11-11    11
27: 2023-11-27    27 2023-11-12    12
28: 2023-11-28    46 2023-11-13    13
29: 2023-11-29    34 2023-11-14    14
30: 2023-11-30   101 2023-11-15    15
```

Comment: This answer is awesome, much cleaner, really like it! Thank you