# Combining a for loop and mutate's case_match within a function

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, mutate

I'm trying to create a function using `mutate` and `case_match` from the `dplyr` package as part of my analytical worfklow. However, to fully automate the process, I want to include an additional dataframe (as an argument in the function) that contains the text string pairs that will be changed if found within the dataframe that contains the data.

Without the for loop, this works perfectly:

```
dftest <- data.frame(old = c("ones","twos","fours","fives"), new = c("Humanoid",
"Hairy","Hairy","what"))
test1 <- data.frame(spp= c("ones", "twos", "threes"), log = c(5,61,36))

updnames <- function(df, col, names_df) {
    require(dplyr)
    if(ncol(names_df)>2)
    {stop("More than 2 columns in names dataframe")}
    if(sum(duplicated(names_df[1]))>0)
    {stop("Duplicate old species names")}
    else
    {
        names_df <- names_df %>% mutate_all(as.character)
        df <- df %>%
                mutate(updnames = case_match({{col}},
                    names_df[1,1] ~ names_df[1,2],
                    names_df[2,1] ~ names_df[2,2],
                    names_df[3,1] ~ names_df[3,2],
                    names_df[4,1] ~ names_df[4,2],
                    .default = {{col}}))}
    return(df)
}

test2 <- updnames(test1, spp,dftest)


> test2 # Correct output
     spp log updnames
1   ones   5 Humanoid
2   twos  61    Hairy
3 threes  36   threes
```

Adding the for loop does not work though. The new column is created as expected, but the column values are simply duplicated:

```
updnames <- function(df, col, names_df) {
  require(dplyr)
  if(ncol(names_df)>2)
  {stop("More than 2 columns in names dataframe")}
  if(sum(duplicated(names_df[1]))>0)
  {stop("Duplicate old species names")}
  else
  {
  names_df <- names_df %>% mutate_all(as.character)
  for(i in 1:nrow(names_df)){
    df <- df %>%
  mutate(updnames = case_match({{col}},
      names_df[i,1] ~ names_df[i,2],
      .default = {{col}}))}
  }
  return(df)
}

test2 <- updnames(test1, spp, dftest)

> test2 # Wrong output
     spp log updnames
1   ones   5     ones
2   twos  61     twos
3 threes  36   threes
```

I tried looking various other posts on Stack Overflow and reading relevant documentation, but I don't seem to be able to figure it out.

If anyone has any ideas, or alternative solutions for what I'm trying to achieve, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I wrote a [blog post](https://tim-tiefenbach.de/post/2023-recode-columns/) about recoding column values and names with dplyr which might be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `recode`.

```
test1 %>% 
  mutate(new_spp = recode(spp, !!!deframe(dftest)))

     spp log  new_spp
1   ones   5 Humanoid
2   twos  61    Hairy
3 threes  36   threes
```

---

In function format do:

```
update_names <- function(df, col, new_names){
     df %>% mutate('{{col}}_new' := recode({{col}},!!!deframe(new_names)))
 }
update_names(test1,spp, dftest)
     spp log  spp_new
1   ones   5 Humanoid
2   twos  61    Hairy
3 threes  36   threes
```

Comment: Hi Samuel, thanks for the quick reply. This does not work on my end. Is new_names just a vector with the new names?

Comment: @Gesler `new_names` is your `dftest` look at how I called the function

Comment: @Gesler Try running without the function. ie the first part only and see whether it works

Comment: It wasn't working because I stupidly named the output dataframe ```df```, which I guess calls the initial object from the function.

Comment: @Gesler quick question.. you used the name Samuel to refer to me. Do you in any way know me?

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfectly now. I didn't look into ```recode``` because in the dplyr documentation it's stated that "recode() is superseded in favor of case_match()". I'm not sure what is best here, but I think it's better to not mark your answer as accepted for now, as relying on functions that are not being maintained is not a futureproof solution.

Comment: I just clicked through to your buymeacoffee page, where your name is listed :)

Comment: @Gesler note that superseded is not deprecated. So the function will always exist. Note that you could use `fct_recode` in case you do not want `recode` but you will have to reverse your name dataframe to new->old ie `test1 %>% mutate(new_spp = fct_recode(spp, !!!deframe(dftest[2:1])))`.

Comment: @Gesler also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77686743/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-group-recode-multiple-categories-into-few-categories/77686935#77686935 for base R options